# LED Strings attached to Arduino programmed to light brighter one after the other repeatedly, stops working after 4 cycles.

Tags: arduino, transition, led, blink

I have made a circuit involving 3 strings of LEDs.
They are supposed to glow at a low intensity initially.

Now when pin 2 on Arduino goes HIGH momentarily, the LED strings glow brighter one by one and then stop. AND, if the pin 2 is kept HIGH, then the transition should continue as long as pin 2 is HIGH.

The problem is that if I make pin 2 HIGH permanently via a push button, the transition occurs 4 times and then it stops. No transition occurs after that even if i again make the pin 2 HIGH after some time.

The code is given below:

```
const int pin1 = 9;
const int pin2 = 10;
const int pin3 = 11;
const int button = 2;
int val = 0;
//int brightness = 0;

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop(){

  while(true)
  {
    val = digitalRead(button);

    if(val == HIGH)
    {
      if(Serial.available())
      {
         long int brightness = Serial.read();

         analogWrite(pin1, 255);
         delay(1000);

         analogWrite(pin2, 255);
         delay(1000);

         analogWrite(pin3, 255);
         delay(1000);

         analogWrite(pin1, brightness);
         analogWrite(pin2, brightness);
         analogWrite(pin3, brightness);
         delay(1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure i completely understand what you try to do, but i can tell you that the `while(true)` loop is entirely useless since the loop function already IS such a loop. Also Serial.read returns an int, not a long int. I would guess that your problem lies in the serial communication. Can you describe what you mean by "and then stop" and by "the transition should continue" (the transition low intensity glow-> brightness value is complete and then?). Maybe there is not enough or too much data in the serial buffer?

Comment: See...What I have to do is make 3 concentric circles of LED strings. There is a push button. Initially, all the LEDs must glow at 50% intensity. WHen the button is pressed, the innermost circle of LEDs must glow at 100% intensity, then the second circle must do the same, and then the outermost circle and finally all the LEDs must dim to 50% intensity again.

Also, if the button is kept pressed, the transition that is radially outwards increase of intensity of LEDs, must occur repeatedly until the button is unpressed.

Comment: The problem I am facing is, that if I press the push button, the transition occurs. This works for exactly 4 times and after that, the intensity of LEDs reduce to around 25% and further switching the push button has no effect.

Comment: So, i assume the brightness value read from Serial indicates 25%, i.e. 64. After the first time, the code returns to the while-loop, recognizes the button is pressed (either again or still pressed), reads a new brightness value from Serial and starts again. After four times or on the fifth press, there is no data available in serial and thus the fifth cycle does not start. As far as i can see there can be no other cause related to the programming part shown here. Try removing the `if(Serial.available)` and set brightness to constant 64. If it works, then Serial is definitively your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to configure your dimmed brightness after each reset of your arduino, you should rearrange your source in a way that reading from the serial port doesn't block your transition, while still making sure your "brightness" has a predefined value:

```
// global variable with preset value    
long int brightness = 64;

// loop function
// http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/Loop
void loop(){
    // check for new brightness value
    if(Serial.available())
    {
         int brightness = Serial.read();
    }
    // check for pressed button
    val = digitalRead(button);
    if(val == HIGH)
    {
         // start light cycle
         analogWrite(pin1, 255);
         delay(1000);

         analogWrite(pin2, 255);
         delay(1000);

         analogWrite(pin3, 255);
         delay(1000);

         analogWrite(pin1, brightness);
         analogWrite(pin2, brightness);
         analogWrite(pin3, brightness);
         delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: While moving the if statement to the top level is a good idea, i must again wonder about the `while(true)`-loop. It is not needed! Initializing brightness with 64 belongs in `setup()`.

Comment: Yes, Thomas, you're right. My post has been edited, unfortunately the necessary setup of the brightness variable is not being reflected by this edit, changing the functionality of the code... :/